# Does Matlab execute .m files differently from automation than from within the GUI?

Tags: windows, matlab, scheduled-tasks

I have a .m script that I've been running using *Windows Task Scheduler,* generally successfully, every 15 minutes for about a year (options: `-automation -minimize -r remotedata -logfile logfile.txt;quit`).

When I run the code manually in Matlab, everything behaves as expected.

However, when it is run as an *automated script,* it has two issues I can't resolve, that seem to indicate **the code is not being executed the same way.**

**First,** I have the following conditional:
`~isempty(remoteData.Time(setdiff(1:end,ni)))` which is terrible syntax, I know, but works just fine when I run the script manually. However, when it runs automated, it gives the error:

```
Error using setdiff (line 80) Not enough input arguments.
```

I corrected it to `~isempty(remoteData.Time(setdiff(1:height(remoteData),ni)))`
but it made me curious.

**Second,** I have a `webread` function with a number of queries (see below) that executes normally when I have it open and hit "run", however, when running as an automation the `dateutc` query is ignored. This one is a bit more puzzling. Can anyone suggest a reason it might be failing to register, or how I might fix it? Debugging is difficult since it works as expected when I run it manually.

```
WUurl = 'http://weatherstation.wunderground.com/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php';
WUID = '***';
WUpwd = '***';
WUdateutc = datestr(datenum(webData.Time(WDNewest-newTimes+i))+7/24,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
WUwindspeedmph = num2str(webData.WndSpd(WDNewest-newTimes+i)*0.62);
WUwinddir = num2str(webData.WndDir(WDNewest-newTimes+i));
WUtempf = num2str(webData.AirTmp(WDNewest-newTimes+i)*1.8+32);
WUrainin = num2str(webData.Rain(WDNewest-newTimes+i)/25.4*4);
WUdailyrainin = num2str(sum(webData.Rain(WDMidnight:WDNewest-newTimes+i))/25.4);
WUbaromin = num2str(webData.BarPress(WDNewest-newTimes+i)*.0295);
WUhumidity = num2str(webData.RelHum(WDNewest-newTimes+i));
gamma = log(webData.RelHum(WDNewest-newTimes+i)/100)+ ...
    (17.67*webData.AirTmp(WDNewest-newTimes+i))/ ...
    (243.5+webData.AirTmp(WDNewest-newTimes+i));
WUdewptf = num2str((243.5*gamma)/(17.67-gamma)*1.8+32);     % Magnus formula estimation
WUsolarradiation = num2str(webData.NetRad_Wm2(WDNewest-newTimes+i));
WUsoiltempf = num2str(nanmean(webData{WDNewest,20:3:77})*1.8+32);
WUsoilmoisture = num2str(nanmean(webData{WDNewest,18:3:75}));

options = weboptions('Timeout',newTimes);
WU_debugging = webread(WUurl,...
    'ID',WUID,...
    'PASSWORD',WUpwd,...
    'dateutc',WUdateutc,...
    'windspeedmph',WUwindspeedmph,...
    'winddir',WUwinddir,...
    'tempf',WUtempf,...
    'rainin',WUrainin,...
    'dailyrainin',WUdailyrainin,...
    'baromin',WUbaromin,...
    'humidity',WUhumidity,...
    'dewptf',WUdewptf,...
    'solarradiation',WUsolarradiation,...
    'soiltempf',WUsoiltempf,...
    'soilmoisture',WUsoilmoisture,...
    'action','updateraw',...
    options);
```